# How do I debug AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException

Tags: automapper

Is there some way to get some more detail from automapper when I get this exception:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
```

Often it will tell me the 2 types of the mapping, but not which resolver or part of the mapping is failing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple answer, is to call this method, preferably in your unit test.

```
// ensure your configuration mappings are loaded first (bootstrapper)
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

see: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-test-my-mappings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2734502/csk Noticed my link was out of date (he could not comment to suggests this link: https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html# ) I did a google and found the one I've used in my answer which looks like an official domain, and which seems to contain the same content.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that fixed my problem was adding this line to the mapping.

```
.ForAllMembers(op=>op.Condition(x=>!x.IsSourceValueNull));
```

Not sure why this isn't the default behavior.

Comment: We got nullable types so it is default to map them too sometimes :) Default is just to map all things, even nulls.